# How to check Query Store settings on model database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, query-store, smo

Query Store can be enabled on the *model* database and ensures that every new database has the same settings as the *model* database.

The GUI option is missing

[image: Missing Query store option in GUI]

But it can be enabled using TSQL

```
ALTER DATABASE model
SET QUERY_STORE = ON (OPERATION_MODE = READ_WRITE);
```

Since there is no GUI, I can't check the default settings there.

Using TSQL again

```
USE model;
select * from sys.database_query_store_options;
```

Returns empty result

[image: Empty result from the model database Query Store settings]

When I create a new database (that uses the model as a template and query the settings, it shows me the result)

```
create database TestQs;
go
use TestQs;
select * from sys.database_query_store_options;
```

[image: Query store options for TestQS database]

Also, the settings must be saved somewhere because when I change the *Query Store* options, the change is propagated to new databases

```
ALTER DATABASE model
SET QUERY_STORE (INTERVAL_LENGTH_MINUTES = 22);
```

I've tried to use SMO to find those options, but no luck.

```
$SqlServer = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server -ArgumentList 'localhost'
$sqlServer.Databases['TestQs'].QueryStoreOptions
```

[image: Database TestQS returns the options]

But the same query for the *model* database yields nothing

```
$SqlServer = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server -ArgumentList 'localhost'
$sqlServer.Databases['model'].QueryStoreOptions
```

[image: Database model returns empty options]

Is there a way to check *Query Store* settings on the *model* database without creating a new database and checking there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to check Query Store settings on the model database without creating a new database and checking there?

Nothing supported, no. QDS is not supposed to be enabled on system databases, workloads shouldn't be running in master or model, for example. I understand the point of view here that it helps with automation, though I'm not a personal fan of putting things in model (or master for that matter) and wouldn't use that approach but rather a programmatic approach so that configuration drift doesn't occur at creation time (continued drift may occur depending on variables, after creation). Still, I get your use case and viewpoint.

> This seems like a bug to me. [...] - Erik Darling

The reason you get nothing back is because QDS shouldn't be enabled on system databases, thus no rowset will be returned. It's not a bug, it was implemented that way.

If you really want this to work you can edit the binary to disable the check, or hot patch with a debugger, but I wouldn't call those supported options.